# Selenium *ElementPresent and *XpathCount give different results?

Tags: selenium

I am getting different results for the same locator. For example

```
//table[@id='foo']
```

returns true when testing `ElementPresent`, but returns 0 for `XpathCount`. In Selenium v1.0.10 IDE the `Find` button highlights the correct element for both functions. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Notes:

- We have frames on the page **EDIT: This is probably the problem. Bounty to verification.**
- There are many tables on the page, but only one with @id of "foo"
- Firefox 3.6
- Happens in both IDE and Java RC

Comment: What is the XML document (please, provide a complete but minimal example)? I don't see any `ElementPresent` element to be referred to in the XPath expression. What are these "both functions"? You have me completely confused here!

Comment: @Dimitre - Let me clarify that this is for the Selenium testing framework (http://seleniumhq.org/) so the XML is an HTML page and the `ElementPresent` and `XpathCount` functions are Selenium functions.

Comment: Could it be related to this bug http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SEL-692

Comment: @jasso - I'm actually using firefox (updated Q) and there isn't an href in the XPath, but thanks for the link.

Comment: This bug seems to be the same issue and suggests that frames may be the issue: http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not a verification more of a non-verification.

I use Selenium to test a GUI with frames. To make isElementPresent and getXpathCount to work I always have to select a frame first with selectFrame (even to get isElementPresent to work correctly). By just opening an URL no frame at all seems to be selected.

This is what the HTML and corresponding selectFrame code looks like:

```
<frameset id="mainframeset"><frame name="nav" id="nav" src....

selenium.selectFrame("nav");
```

Comment: Thanks ygram! The fact that you have had success with frames by setting suggests that maybe I am not correctly selecting the right frame.

Comment: In my experience it is hard to make test cases work perfectly when using selenium and frames. You can experiment with selectWindow(null) before selecting frame, and waitForFrameToLoad or waitForPageToLoad. I also have javascript that make things even messier. But it is possible to make it work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Use these XPath expressions**:

```
boolean(//table[@id='foo'])
```

and

```
count(//table[@id='foo'])
```

In case there is a `table` element whose `id` attribute's value is `"foo"`, then the first expression above should evalute to `true()` and the second expression above should evalute to a positive integer.

Comment: Dimitre, I don't think you understand the context. This is using *Selenium* where the function names are `verifyElementPresent`, `assertElementPresent`, `assertXpathCount`, `storeXpathCount`, etc. The problem I am having is that the `*ElementPresent` is `true`, but `*XpathCount` is recording `0`.

Comment: @Adam: I do understand the context and it is clear that you have problems using these two Selenium functions. Exactly due to this reason I am giving you two XPAth expressions to use *instead* of those functions, and this eliminates your problem completely. I *have solved* your problem, eliminating it.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to use the XPath functions inside of Selenium. `selenium.getEval("count(//table[@id='foo']//tr)")` throws a `SeleniumException` for a syntax error

Comment: Is it maybe not possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554964/selenium-how-do-i-execute-an-xpath-function-or-expression-in-my-test/615853#615853

Comment: @Adam: I don't know Selenium, but most XPath engines typically provide a way to evaluate any XPath expression, including expressions that do not return a node or a node-set. Read the Selenium documentation and find the right way to do this, too.

Comment: @Dimitre, Selenium generally makes use of browser built-in XPath engines. I believe the limitation is in the client API that manipulates the browser. After about an hour of looking I can't find a way to run your XPath functions. Thank you for your help and expertise though.

Comment: @Adam: If the language processor you are using cannot evaluate some kinds of XPath expressions, then this is *not* a compliant XPath engine and the question should not be tagged "xpath".

Comment: @Adam: Please, read the Selenium documentation. I found a description how expressions like the ones in my answer can be evaluated: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/storeassertXpath

Comment: @Dimitre I'll change the tagging if it bothers you. I wasn't trying to say there was a problem with the Firefox XPath engine, but with the way that Selenium uses the XPath engine. Thanks for pointing me to that user extension. I'll see if I can get approval to use it.

Comment: @Adam: Get approval? This should *never* be necessary, even if you are working for the military. Anyway, I provided the right (and probably the best so far) answer and you need to recognize this fact.

Comment: @Adam: What is the bounty for? I can't quite understand.

Comment: @Dimitre I can't speak to the approval process with you and your aggressive nature is offputting. I do not feel you have given the best answer, because your answer does not work in the Selenium product without third party add-ons. Thank you for your attention and time on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to the question, but a workaround if you are reading this and want to loop over the elements. Use `isElementPresent` in the for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 2; selenium.isElementPresent("//table[@id='foo']//tr["+i+"]"); i++)
{
    selenium.getText("//table[@id='foo']//tr["+i+"]//td["+columnNum+"]");
}
```

*Note that we start i at 2 since XPath is indexed from 1 and we want to skip the header*